# Passing a data frame from-to R and C using .call()

Tags: c, r

Is there a general way of passing a data frame with arbitrary columns (integer/factor, numeric, character data) from r to c and back?  Pointers to close enough examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

RT

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A data.frame is a list, so along the lines of

```
#include <Rdefines.h>

SEXP df_fun(SEXP df)
{
    int i, len = Rf_length(df);
    SEXP result;
    PROTECT(result = NEW_CHARACTER(len));
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        switch(TYPEOF(VECTOR_ELT(df, i))) {
        case INTSXP:
            SET_STRING_ELT(result, i, mkChar("integer"));
            break;
        case REALSXP:
            SET_STRING_ELT(result, i, mkChar("numeric"));
            break;
        default:
            SET_STRING_ELT(result, i, mkChar("other"));
            break;
        };
        UNPROTECT(1);
    return result;
}
```

and then after `R CMD SHLIB df_fun.c`

```
> dyn.load("df_fun.so")
> df=data.frame(x=1:5, y=letters[1:5], z=pi, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> .Call("df_fun", df)
[1] "integer" "other"   "numeric"
```

Use `GET_CLASS`, `GET_ATTR` and other macros in Rdefines.h (or their equivalent functions, like `getAttrib`) to discover other information about the data frame. Note though that a data.frame has an API that can differ from its structure. So for instance the R function `row.names` can return something different from the value stored in the row.names attribute. I think most `.Call` functions operate on atomic vectors, keeping the manipulation of more complicated objects at the R level.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Martin. What other attributes of a data frame (nrows, rownames, colnames, is.factor etc.) can I query when passing a DF and set when returning a DF ? RT

Comment: I added a few sentences about this to the end of the answer

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [link to an example using C++ and package inline](http://www.mail-archive.com/rcpp-devel@lists.r-forge.r-project.org/msg01720.html) by Dirk Eddelbeuttel:

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. C++ is not an option as I am restricted to c by design.

Comment: Why the restriction on C?  For R, you are bound to use gcc which means you can use g++ just as easily.  Easier APIs trump harder APIs every time.  Oh, and the example pointed to by DWin can as easily return a data.frame too.

Comment: Restriction was a euphemism for my own ignorance! But the reward is worth the effort.  Thanks for the package. RT

Answer (score 1):

**data.frame type is a list with "data.frame" attribute.**

This is example of creating data.frame in source of R *(src/library/stats/src/model.c)*:

```
/* Turn the data "list" into a "data.frame" */
/* so that subsetting methods will work. */

PROTECT(tmp = mkString("data.frame"));
setAttrib(data, R_ClassSymbol, tmp);
UNPROTECT(1);
```

You can *simulate* data.frame manually this way:

```
l <- list(1:5)
attr(l, "class") <- "data.frame"
attr(l, "names") <- "Column 1"
attr(l, "row.names") <- paste("Row ", 1:5)
```