# Process list from R to C and access it

Tags: c, r

I would like to use a list in C, that i got from R. I realise the question is very similar to this: [Passing a data frame from-to R and C using .call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658168/passing-a-data-frame-from-to-r-and-c-using-call). 
However, I fail in storing it in a pointer "*target", from where i would further use it.

R:

```
.Call("processlist", list(c(1,2), c(1,3,2), c(1,5,4,4)))
```

and in C:

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

extern "C" {
     SEXP processlist(SEXP lst);
}

SEXP processlist(SEXP lst){
   SEXP vec  = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, 2));
   SET_VECTOR_ELT(vec, 0, VECTOR_ELT(c, 0);
   SET_VECTOR_ELT(vec, 1, VECTOR_ELT(c, 1);
   SET_VECTOR_ELT(vec, 2, VECTOR_ELT(c, 2);

   const lngth = 3;
   int *target[lnght];

   // Here i want to fill "target", but how?
   int *preTarget = INTEGER(vec);

   // Bad attempts
   target[0] = INTEGER(preTarget[0]);
   target[0] = INTEGER(vec[0]);
}
```

Note: C++ is not an Option unfortunately.

Edit: Desired output would be that I can call *target the following way.

```
target[0][0] --> Returns: 1
target[1][2] --> Returns: 2
target[2][3] --> Returns: 4
```

Calling "vec" in that way throws me an error at the moment.

Comment: When you say you want to fill `target`, are you wanting to flatten the list to make a single-dimensional array, or create a ragged array? This could help make a complete answer. There are several typos and you haven't quite used `INTEGER` the right way to access the elements of `vec`, so while as of now I could add an answer that fixes those things and makes your code compilable, I don't know if it would accomplish what you want. Can you add more clarifying info as to the objective you want to accomplish with the function?

Comment: thanks for your comment. The list should not be flattened. I made an edit to clarify the desired Output. Hope it helps. The question might be actually be very easy, i am very new to C :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that you just want to access the values in the list from the C side. If that's correct, look at the code below.

In `d.c`:

```
/* Including some headers to show the results*/
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
SEXP processlist(SEXP lst){
   int i,l = length(lst);
   /* You need an array of arrays, so target will be an int** */ 
   int **target = malloc(sizeof(int *)*l);
   for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
     target[i] = INTEGER(VECTOR_ELT(lst,i));
   }
   printf("target[0][0]: %d\n",target[0][0]);
   printf("target[1][2]: %d\n",target[1][2]);
   printf("target[2][3]: %d\n",target[2][3]);
   free(target);
   return R_NilValue;
}
```

The important thing to notice is that `target` has to be an `int**`, since it is a pointer to an array of pointers.

In `d.R` (after `d.c` has been compiled):

```
dyn.load("d.so")
mylist<-list(c(1,2), c(1,3,2), c(1,5,4,4))
#This is very important: by default 1 in R is double. 
#You need to coerce every element of the list to integer.
mylist<-lapply(mylist,as.integer)
.Call("processlist", mylist)
```

Note that we need to coerce each element of the list to integer. The above produces:

```
target[0][0]: 1
target[1][2]: 2
target[2][3]: 4
```

Comment: works for me thanks! Will have to wait a few more hours to Award the bounty though. A minor difference for me: (Instead of `malloc(sizeof(int *)*l);` i have to use `(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*l);` to make it work.

Comment: Note; a nice alternative to `target = malloc(sizeof(int *)*l);` is `target = malloc(sizeof *target * l);` which is easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: @ThanksGuys Concerning "i have to use `(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*l);`": what C compiler are you using?  Or are you using a non-C  compiler like C++?

Comment: About casting `malloc`, one of the most famous SO questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: ah well :) Thanks a lot, i learned a lot from your answer. I tried to adapt the code to process strings, but got stock after a few hours. I know it is a new idea. Therefore, I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231159/process-list-of-strings-from-r-to-c. I would be very thankful for any hints :) Thanks a lot again!